# Error message: expected initializer before 'switch'

Tags: c++, switch-statement, initializer

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()

switch(age)
{
case 1:
case 2:
case 3:
case 4:
cout<< "Tricycle"<<endl;
break;
case 5:
.
.
case 15:
if (15 >= age >= 5)
cout<< "Bicycle"<<endl;
break;
case 16:
case 17:
cout<<"Motorcycle"<<endl;
break;
default:
cout<< "Motor car"<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Error message:

> Expected initializer before switch

I tried declaring `age` as an integer...but still I get an error message.

Comment: `int main() { return 0; }`. Get that to work, then add your switch statement and a definition of `age`.

Comment: I just edited and completed the code and yet i still get the same error.

Comment: What value are you expecting variable `age` to have? Why?

Comment: `15 >= age >= 5` is a common error for beginners. It makes sense in math, but not in programming. You have to use two comparisons, joined with "and":  `15 >= age && age >= 5`

Comment: “I just edited …” — show the code as you edited it. Nobody can tell you what’s wrong with code they can’t see.

Comment: The code lacks indentation, that's why you are making mistakes of not noticing missing braces.

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes in your code:

> ```
> int main()
> ```

You are missing an opening `{` after `main()`.

> ```
> switch(age)
> ```

You did not declare `age`, or give it a value, before trying to use it.

> ```
> .
> .
> ```

Simply not value code.  So I *assume* you did this only for demonstration purposes here, and in your real code you are actually spelling out each `case` individually.

> ```
> if (15 >= age >= 5)
> ```

This simply does not do what you think it does.  C++ comparisons do not work this way. You need separate expressions to compare `age` to each value individually.

Not to mention, if you have individual `case` statements for `5`..`15`, then this `if` is completely redundant anyway.

> ```
> return 0;
> }
> ```

You are missing a closing `}` on the `switch` block before `return`.

With that said, try the following instead:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int age;

    cout << "Enter an age: ";
    if ( (!(cin >> age)) || (age <= 0) ) {
        cout << "Invalid input!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    switch (age)
    {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
        cout << "Tricycle" << endl;
        break;
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
    case 10:
    case 11:
    case 12:
    case 13:
    case 14:
    case 15:
        cout << "Bicycle" << endl;
        break;
    case 16:
    case 17:
        cout << "Motorcycle" << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Motor car" << endl;
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, using `if` instead of `switch`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int age;

    cout << "Enter an age: ";
    if ( (!(cin >> age)) || (age <= 0) ) {
        cout << "Invalid input!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if ( /*age >= 1 &&*/ age <= 4) { // age >= 1 is always true here!
        cout << "Tricycle" << endl;
    }
    else if ( /*age >= 5 &&*/ age <= 15) { // age >= 5 is always true here!
        cout << "Bicycle" << endl;
    }
    else if ( /*age >= 16 &&*/ age <= 17) { // age >= 16 is always true here!
        cout << "Motorcycle" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Motor car" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```